# jQuery UI Tooltip and AJAX, how to implement live() with it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, tooltip

On certain pages I have code like `$('.tooltip').tooltip();`. Example element would look like:

`<a title="Tooltip content" class="tooltip" href="javascript:void(0);"><img src="icon.png" /></a>`

This works beautifully unless I want to reload those elements with AJAX. Then, the tooltip handlers are not reattached to the new content and the tooltips do not work any more.

I have attempted to do a workarounds to somehow reattach the tooltip to the elements with no particular success. Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: Why wont you simply reinitialize it in the AJAX `success` function?

Comment: Just call `$(".tooltip").tooltip()` again.

Comment: `live()` is not appropriate for calling a plugin method. As mentioned initialize within ajax success callback

Comment: reattach the tooltips again at the result of your ajax call:  $.ajax(*your ajax call*).done(function( msg ) { *reattach the tooltips*});

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to reinitialise tool-tip `$('.tooltip').tooltip();` in your AJAX success callback

Answer (score 1):

You can reinitialise tooltip for new added elements only by:

```
$('.tooltip').not('.hasTooltip').tooltip().addClass('hasTooltip');
```